# Why do I get a purple screen whilst installing Ubuntu Server 11.04

Tags: installation, server

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 11.04 on an 64-bit AMD machine. The install goes fine until after "Loading additional components", then I get a blank purple screen with a responsive cursor at the bottom.

I've looked everywhere and can't find anything (all the documentation seems to be on the desktop version). I have a wireless card installed if that makes a difference, don't why it would. This happens regardless of whether `nomodeset` is set or not.

Here's what it looks like (as described):

[image: purple screen]

Specs:

- CPU - [64-bit AMD Sempron 140 @ 2.7Ghz](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103698)
- RAM - [1Gb DDR3 1333](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820134787)
- HDD - [WD 500Gb 7200RPM SATA 3.0Gb/s](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136073)
- Mobo -  [Foxconn M61PMP-K](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813186189)
- Wireless Card - [Rosewill RNX-G300LX](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833166021)

Comment: Are you installing off the ISO or using wubi?

Comment: could you walk us throw how you installed ubuntu? how did you exactly do? what hardware do you have?

Comment: I created a bootable USB from the .iso using the USB-Installer tool. I just put the USB drive in, booted, hit "install Ubuntu server", chose my keyboard layout, then it gets past a few loading bars and right after the "loading additional components" bar completes it goes to this screen. I can type in the bottom but that's it.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I just had the same issue, but after some minutes, while I was researching this, the setup continued. So chances are, similar cases will turn out the same way, if you apply enough patience.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a wireless card you may need to install the [Ubuntu mini.iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD). It has better kernel support by using the generic kernel as opposed to the optimized server kernel. This will install the base system, no GUI, and you can install the LAMP stack after that.

Comment: I tried removing the wireless card and it does the exact same thing. I've added the exact specs to my original post. The PC does not have a CD drive and the universal USB installer does not seem to support the mini.iso. Suggestions?